# Cakephp 2.0 row/record-level Acl

Tags: acl, cakephp-2.0

i am messing around with the cakephp 2.0's access lists,
so far i created a very simple example following the documentation.

I have set up a users table and the most important functions like index, add, login ecc. and is related to a groups table (every user belongs to a group).

I've also created a "houses" table wich contain different contents (houses).

Then i've set up auth in combination with the acl-component in crud mode,
including the aco and aro tree.

So far so good, everything is working so far, i can allow or deny single actions for every user.
But, i want further access control, that for instance a user can manage only a specific house.
So i've set up an aco for every house, allowed only read-access to the houses to the user and allowed update access only for the desired house.
But it won't work! No matter what i do.. i don't get access to the edit action.
Here my trees:

```
Aco:
[1] Houses
  [5] House.1
  [6] House.2
[2] Users

Aro:
[1] superadmin
  [4] User.1
[1] admin
  [5] User.2
  [7] User.4
[3] customer
  [6] User.3
```

And finally the aros_acos table:

```
id  aro_id  aco_id  _create _read   _update _delete

4   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   1   2   1   1   1   1
6   2   1   1   1   1   1
7   3   1   0   1   0   0
8   7   1   -1  1   1   -1
9   7   5   1   1   1   1
```

Fact is, that, if i try to do a quick check with:

```
 var_dump($this->Acl->check(
array('model' => 'User', 
'foreign_key' => 4),
array('model' => 'House',
'foreign_key' => 1),
'update'));
```

It gives back true!

Strange... Am i doing something wrong? Is there any way to decently debug the acl component (with information wich acos and aros the component is checking, seeing ecc.)?

Comment: Any update on this question, I am also trying to achieve the row level control with CakePHP ACL ver 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your aro_aco table, it looks like this is correct behavior. User.4 belongs to the admins group which has update permission. set to true in row 8.  You have a rule in row 8 specifically for User.4, but you have granted update permission specifically to that user in that row.  It appears that the ACL rules are working exactly as you have them setup.  To prevent User.4 from using the update permission, run this at the cake command line to update your rules for User.4:

```
cake acl deny User.4 House.1 update
```

It should then return false when you run a check:

```
cake acl check User.4 House.1 update
```

**EDIT**

I'm going to attempt to revise this based on comments left below.  I think that you may still be setting up the rules incorrectly.  I am going to use the command line examples (because it's either to both type and to do in practice) but you can just as easily write the PHP to do this.  My examples below also focus on admin, but you could use for the superadmin and users groups too.

First, deny everything to admins since we want to grant permissions individually:

```
cake acl deny admin Houses all
```

Then, grant the read only permission to admin so they can all read Houses:

```
cake acl grant admin Houses read
```

Lastly, grant the update permission to the specific user that gets update privileges:

```
cake acl grant User.4 Houses.1 update
```

These permissions should allow User.4 to read and update the House record.  Keep in mind that if you have already created deny or allow records for User.4 then this example may not work.  You may want to truncate your aco_aro table and start over since it's small at this point.

If all acl checks work, but the behavior is still incorrect, then you may have an issue with how the ACL component is authorizing an action.  You may have to tweak those settings in $beforeFilter or your $components array.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your response!
That seems to work correctly, but if i try to edit that house via the web-interface, it says i don't have access to that resource.

I've also tried to set up the rules manually like this:
$this->Acl->deny(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 4), 'Houses');
$this->Acl->allow(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 4), 'Houses', 'read');
$this->Acl->allow(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 4), array('model' => 'House', 'foreign_key' => 1));

However, if i allow the user 4 to have update access to the entire House model, it works.

Thanks again
alex

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what's happening now. If the user has update access to the House model, but denies update access on House.4, then it should not give you update access there. Are you still looking for the check to return false, or have you solved that part?

Comment: Well no, i think made some mistakes describing my problem:
What i want to achieve is, that a group of users (administrators) have read-only access to all of the records, but update access to some of them.
Up here, i tried to do the following: 1.) Deny access to the user (later on, i'll do that for the user-group, but for simplicity i only modify the single user)    2.) Allow read-only access for the user for all of the records    3.) Allow the user to update one specific record.
Am i doing something wrong?

10000000000 thanks again!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some steps that I think may help based on what I understand. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks again,
i've run these commands successfully (one mod: instead of Houses.1 i used House.1, since it is the model-name).
But it won't let me edit the record...  strange.. I'm pretty shure it is a simple, little and stupid mistake i made somewhere...
Is it right that row-based acl is possible without modifications in cakephp?

Comment: In 1.3 it wasn't supported, and was enough of a sore point that many people made plugins to try to address it (SuperAuth, Permissionable behavior, etc). I'm really curious about this too for 2.0 so I hope we can figure this out.

Comment: How have you implemented the ACL check?  Are you using actions, CRUD, or performing the check directly before the update action takes place?

Comment: Hi,
i use auth in crud mode for checking authorization and at action level it works like it should, but not for single records..
Can it be that cake still does not support row-level acl without plugins... =(    Could that be?

Comment: I have it properly checking acl at the row level, but I have implemented code that checks to see if the user has access to that record befor the edits...similar to what you are doing.  It is certainly possible, and it was under 1.3 too.  It's just not built in.  You should be able to do this without writing much code.  Any chance you could post your controller so we can take a look?

Comment: Yeah sure, i've created a zip containing the three controllers and uploaded them here:
http://www.alex-franzelin.it/downloads/Controller.zip

Note that this is only an example project to try out the acl functionality, so most of the code is coming fresh out the bake shell.

Comment: Anyone found out something?
Because the final goal i want to achieve is the following:
- every admin user has a number (14-17 characters long)
- every record that a user can edit has a 19 character long number
- the user can edit the records that begin with his num
            
example: user with the number 1231201230132 can edit all records that begin with this sequence.