# Row-level ACL in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-4, row-level-security

Is it possible to create row-level authentication in Laravel 4? Is there any bundle or package for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new Laravel 4 ACL component that you can use:

https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/laravel-acl

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. When I update my composer, I get an error saying that this is not compatible with Laravel 4.2 and I need to downgrade to Laravel 4.0.x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any packages for that.

And to understand your question better:
I suppose you mean adding a 'user_id' of 'group_id' column to your table and filter on those?

[edit]
If that is the case, you can simply add `->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)` to your queries.

Comment: i need same functionality explained for cakephp in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149860/cakephp-2-0-row-record-level-acl

Comment: after a little search I found: http://vespakoen.github.com/authority-laravel/, it's build for laravel-3, perhaps the author will rebuild it to laravel-4?

Comment: i also get one http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry2/authentication  Sentry 2, but problem is that it is not providing Row Level Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As of laravel 4 its not advisable to use bundles, we can use packages for it.
I haven't really tried using it but seems like it can work:
[click here](https://packagist.org/packages/alaxos/acl)
If not you can find all most all packages for the site mentioned above.

You can update the composer.json with that particular package name and install it using

```
php composer.phar update
```

Please let me know if it works :)

Thanks :)

Comment: i agree with you bundle and packages have a same like functionality so can u please suggest me a good packages for it?

Comment: I too need to implement ACL functionality but not able to do it, i installed this https://packagist.org/packages/problematic/acl-manager-bundle pkg, u too can try using it. I dont know how to proceed further after insalling it. You can also look into the link above in my post.

Comment: Well You're trying to install packages from different frameworks. There's a big chance that they won't work in L4.

Comment: agree with radmen, because acl-manager-bundle uses doctrine for CRUD operation so it is not convenient with Laravel .

Comment: @radmen any  idea what to use for ALC implementation ?? Please help !!

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal to be honest I have no idea (didn't need to use something like this).

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I have one idea, but it's not an easy solution. You could try binding to Eloquent's events (creating/updating/deleting). When callback assigned to event will return FALSE the operation will be canceled. Problem with this is that You need to implement it manually ..