# Using ACL to find data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, acl

I use CakePHP 2.4.5 and I'm looking at ACL. I see that it can be used as a gatekeeper before fetching data from the database.
Now I wish to do a `->find('all')` on the data and get returned only the allowed items from the database. To speak in the CakePHP tutorial's terms: "*I'm Aragorn and give me all items I'm allowed to see/read*".
Is this what ACL can do for me? Or is this something I can only achieve by modifying my query conditions?

thanks!
Bart

Comment: I think, you are looking for record level acl implementation. This may help you:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149860/cakephp-2-0-row-record-level-acl

Comment: Thanks. It seems your reference still speaks of `check` per record with knowledge about the record ID. I would like to do a `findAll()` that automatically leaves out not permitted records. Without knowning in advance the ID's of the records.

Comment: IN such case you've to define your own find type. Follow the link for more details. http://www.codeforest.net/cakephp-tip-custom-find-types

Comment: The question you asked is not related to you actual question - I have done this method of find('all') the permission functions and it will work. IT is nice and neat codeing. I Followed this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIjfwqqGRhs like (how ever it is in Brazilian langauage but it's really worthed [I am Persian]) if you got any question ask will be glad to help you with

Comment: Consider filtering your rows in the [beforeFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforefind) callback of the AppModel E.g. if you were doing a find on the Post model, setup all the rows of the Post model as ACOs. Now in the acos table, you will have a row with the 'model' = 'Post' and 'foreign_key' = '2' where 2 is the id of the row in the posts table and so on. Then you will do a Acl::check() in the beforeFind() callback to filter rows from the Post table that are allowed in your aros_acos table. Do consider the effects this will have on performance.